# Cannot connect to websocket

Tags: android, websocket, springboot

When I tried to connect to spring boot web socket from android stomp client, it is not connecting and the catalina log shows

```
Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null
```

Tomcat server is running behind apache and the apache server runs on https. **I haven't added https in tomcat** .All the http requests are redirected to https this is how I tried to connect to the websocket

```
mStompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.JWS, "wss://chat.example.com/ws/chat/websocket", headers);
```

but it works when running in local machine

```
mStompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.JWS, "http://10.0.2.2:8080/chat/ws/chat/websocket", headers);
```

this is my stomp end point setup

```
registry.addEndpoint("/chat").setHandshakeHandler(new HandShakeHandler()).withSockJS();
```

I have enabled `mod proxy wstunnel` and in the virtual host config i have added

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/chat/
proxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/chat/
ProxyPass /wss/ ws://localhost:8080/chat/
```

Anybody know how to fix this. Any help will be appreciated. Please ask if you need more details

Comment: In your request the path is `/ws/chat/websocket` but in your apache config you only mention a rule beginning with `/wss`. typo?

Comment: no, I have tried that too